# DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges() not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC 4 with EF Code First 5.  I'm a little new, and so am just creating a project from the default template.

The project is speaking to the database and records are persisting.  We use DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges at work, and I'm attempting to get it working with the default template project.  I found the SetInitializer call down in the SimpleMembershipInitializer for the template project, and have been attempting to use this:

```
            Database.SetInitializer<NPContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<NPContext>());
```

instead of

```
            Database.SetInitializer<NPContext>(null);
```

It isn't working - information will still persist to the database but it is not dropped and recreated with the new schema.  I also tried setting the initializer in Application_Start().  I get no crash or visible error when in debug mode.

I am not incredibly familiar with setting up the tools that I'm using, and I tried fishing around for setting database permissions(I'm using SQLEXPRESS but I do have SQL Management Studio 2012), but wasn't sure what the user would be or what permission to set.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?  I'm spinning my wheels and wasting hours at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do this in my application using `Application_Start()`. First, I have an initializer class that handles seeding my database when it is recreated:

```
public class MyContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>
{
    // Seed your database or anything else you want to do
}
```

Then in `Application_Start()` set your initializer:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MyContextInitializer());
```